# How to pass through web service call to another server?

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework

There are two web applications (exampleA.com and exampleB.com). What I'd like to do is pass through every call that is made to exampleA.com to exampleB.com - so in fact exampleA.com would work only as a proxy server. Both applications are build on Zend Framework 1.11.11 and use Zend_Soap_*.

I could make a 302 Redirect (and I will anyway) but, as I believe, there is no guarantee that WS Client will follow that redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the IP of exampleA.com to be the same as exampleB.com & add the alias exampleA.com to the vhost of exampleB.com

Comment: Unfortunately, this is something I cannot do.